# Snowflake condition type on semi-structured data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake I have a column that holds a semi-structured data that should hold numbers but as of semi-structured data nature, that is not strict. I want to check the type of data and convert to float if possible. Something like that:

```
SELECT IFF(TYPEOF(column_name::data_name) is NUMBER, column_name::data_name::FLOAT, null)
FROM some_table
```

How can I make this query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TRY_TO_DOUBLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_double.html) is the tool you are looking for if you want it to be floating point. Otherwise if only Integer TRY_TO_NUMBER

```
SELECT try_to_double(column_name::data_name::TEXT)
FROM some_table
```

Here the DB doesn't like output of type VARAINT, which is what selecting a value from a VARAINT gives you. The way around this is turn it into a TEXT first:

```
SELECT 
    parse_json('{"data_name":3.14, "it_is_a_number":1234}') as column_name
    ,try_to_double(column_name:data_name::text) as dub
    ,try_to_number(column_name:it_is_a_number::text) as int
    ;
```

| COLUMN_NAME | DUB | INT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| { "data_name": 3.14, "it_is_a_number": 1234 } | 3.14 | 1,234 |

Comment: It produces an error `Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and FLOAT`.

Comment: The DB is a little picky, which is not helpful. But cast it to `::TEXT` the value pulled from the JSON is VARIANT but looks like a TEXT/STRING..